# NGINX bad URL after Rewrite

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm currently rewriting a URL to get rid of the nasty GET parameters.
My intention is to rewrite "`index.php?do=show&id=1`" to "`/show/1`"

But after the "redirect" `/show/` stays in the URL. So `/index.php` becomes `/show/index.php` automatically.

What's wrong with my config?

```
    server {
        listen       80;

        server_name  xxxxxx.de www.xxxxxx.de;
        root /var/www/xxxxxx/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                if (!-e $request_filename){
                        rewrite ^/show/(.*)$ /index.php?do=show&id=$1 last; break;
                }
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Solution found: Changed the HREF from index.php to /index.php - now everything works as it should.

Comment: I'm not a rewrite expert, but I *think* the problem might be your match group (.*) is what gets replaced, and therefore you need to include /show/ in that if you want it to be replaced as well.